# how to get server response and if server response is "Success" after show alert by JSON using objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

```
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usertxt.text,pwdtxt.text,[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
```

// preaparing URL request to send data.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:URL_PATH];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:7.0];

NSURLResponse *_response;
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&_response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

//Print Server Response

```
NSLog(@"Login response:%@",str);
```

//Parse JSON string into an NSDictionary

```
 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&error];
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting and explain the issue. You can't just post a bunch of code with no explanation at all. What is the issue with this code? What do you need help with?

Comment: -1 there does not appear to be a question here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This
 Don't need to use JSON simply try this code to get response from server

```
NSString *string= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);
        NSString *str1 = @"1";
        if ([str isEqualToString:str1 ])
        {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Successfully" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Try Again" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Later" otherButtonTitles:@"Call", nil];
            alert.tag = 1;
            [alert show];
        }
```

if your response string is `success` than put this in the place of `@"1"`

Comment: hi kapil thanks for ur help!i already received "Login Reponse {"respose" : "success"}.now i want if response params success after show alert otherwise show error alert...

Comment: alreday?? you solve your problam or not...

Comment: ok than code work for you just put success in the place or @"1" like this NSString *str1 = @"success";

Comment: NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usertxt.text,pwdtxt.text,[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];      //i need to inclucde my input field textbox with params...

Comment: this is what this is url NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url.php?username=%@&password=%@",usertxt.text,pwdtxt.text]; right   don't need to put this line [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] just add my code and than try

Comment: my op now  :2013-08-16 11:23:54.069 FlashHunt[1782:1a603] responseData: (null)
2013-08-16 11:23:54.069 FlashHunt[1782:1a603] responseData:

Comment: ok that means you getting null as response please told your php developer or who make this web service to give responce data as 1/0 1 for success and 0 for failure.

Comment: but thats show else part only!

Comment: that means your code is fine  bcoz you got response please check for data you submite or sever side issue

Comment: 1. Don't use ASCII encoding. Use UTF8.

Comment: 1. data should have given you a warning. Fix it. 2. You are sending a password over http. Show that code to your boss. 3. Don't use ASCII encoding. Use UTF8. 4. That ACCEPT header looks seriously dodgy. 5. initWithRequest copies the contents of the URL request, so all the later changes are for nothing. 6. Which doesn't matter because you never use the connection. I think that's enough for now.